# xlsm file being added to a disabled list

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, vba

I have a C# console application that runs many Excel macros.

Each macro makes use of a shared read-only xlsm file that contains many helper functions "helperroutinesnetwork.xlsm". It is effectively a factory for lots of shared `vba` functionality.

If the C# console crashes irretrievably, when a workbook plus helperroutinesnetwork are open we are finding that the helper workbook gets effectively blacklisted and added to Excel's disabled books.

What this means is that any subsequent macros that need the helper book cannot find or use it until we manually move it out of the Disable list like so:

[image]

Is it possible to either:

1. Write a script that detects if it has been added to the disabled list and even to enable it?
2. Ensure it is always protected and never allowed to be added to the Disabled add-ins list?